# "Skipping blanks"

Tags: google-sheets

I have a huge data sheet that is being updated every week. It has  about 2,000 colums and 6 rows.

Every cell each week is new (Its a list of average prices, so the names of the items remain the same but the prices fluctuate.)

However, there are about 100 prices that *have* to be the same each week. I need to be able to copy and paste these values in without deleting the other values.

For example:

[image]

So when copy and pasting a chunk of the sheet with a few numbers scattered within it, the blank spaces do not replace existing values when pasted in.

Comment: it looks like it has de-formatted my example. fixed

Comment: You can put pre-formatted text by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an explicit "copy except blanks" command, but the following approach seems simple enough. For this illustration I assume the original data is in the   rows 1-6, while the "scattered" data to be pasted there is in rows 7-12.

Put the following, for example, in A14:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(7:12),7:12,1:6))
```

This will fill the rows 14-19 with the data combined in the way you described. Then copy these rows and paste them to the top of the spreadsheet with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>  (equivalently, right click -> paste special -> values only).

Explanation: the IF command takes values from rows 7:12 when they have positive length (i.e., are nonempty). Otherwise it takes them from rows 1:6.